# How do I download drivers for Broadcom 4311 802.11 from another PC and install them on 13.04?

Tags: drivers, broadcom

How do I download drivers for Broadcom 4311 802.11 from another PC and install them on 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can either download the source .tar.gz from the Broadcom website or the in my opinion much better way is to download the .deb with:

```
apt-get download broadcom-sta-common
```

It is then in the directory from where you called it and you can copy it onto the flash drive.

If you have no other linux available use [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) to download the .deb.

On your other machine simply open the .deb with the Software Center or use

```
sudo dpkg --install /path/to/your/XX.deb
```

Comment: Where do I go to download the deb? The other PC is Windows XP. Where do I get Linux package?

Comment: you can use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search for packages online and download them without linux

Answer (score 0):

You sure it's the drivers? I had the same problem and a similar chip.

I used `sudo rfkill unblock all` and it works like a dream now.